# How do I remove the last comma from a string using PHP?

Tags: php, string, substr

I am using a loop to get values from my database and my result is like:

```
'name', 'name2', 'name3',
```

And I want it like this:

```
'name', 'name2', 'name3'
```

I want to remove the comma after the last value of the loop.

Comment: You should `implode` your original values with commas, not loop over them and remove stuff at the end.

Answer (score 276, accepted):

You may use the [`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) function. The following code will remove all trailing commas:

```
rtrim($my_string, ',');
```

The Second parameter indicates characters to be deleted.

Comment: Also make sure you don't have any trailing space after the comma, otherwise this will fail, or do rtrim(trim($my_string), ',').

Comment: This doesn't work in a loop that adds a comma at the end as it will remove all the commas.

Comment: to expand on @Foxhoundn's answer you can use just use ```rtrim($my_string, ', ');``` with an added space in the second parameter if you have trailing space

Answer (score 31):

Try:

```
$string = "'name', 'name2', 'name3',";
$string = rtrim($string,',');
```

Comment: I already tried it but its showing like this:
'name''name2''name3'

This is not what I need

Comment: Per your example, you need to apply this function only on the final result and not on each value separately.

Comment: I am using loop so how can I know the final result of loop ?

Comment: The final result of the loop is stored in a variable, right? So apply the `rtrim` call to that variable. If you're still having difficulty, update your question with the code that produces the loop.

Comment: I like this answer in particular, because one of the issues with a lot of PHP built-in functions, is that some of them are void, and some of them have return types. In this case, I was trying to just write `rtrim($string, ',')`, when I should be writing `$string = rtrim($string, ',');`

Comment: @Alec: Afaik, most of the [String functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) have a return value. Void funcitons that directly modify the parameter can be for arrays or objects. (sorry a bit OT but can help memorize it!)

Answer (score 16):

Try the below code:

```
$my_string = "'name', 'name2', 'name3',";
echo substr(trim($my_string), 0, -1);
```

Use this code to remove the last character of the string.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `substr` function to remove this.

```
$t_string = "'test1', 'test2', 'test3',";
echo substr($t_string, 0, -1);
```

Answer (score 7):

`rtrim` function

```
rtrim($my_string,',');
```

Second parameter indicates that comma to be deleted from right side.

Answer (score 6):

It is better to use implode for that purpose. Implode is easy and awesome:

```
    $array = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'];
    $str = implode(', ', $array);
```

Output:

```
    name1, name2, name3
```

Comment: It's uneccessary to generate an array first out of database-read values.   rtrim & substr are both valid - and good - solutions.

Comment: Well, you're right but if you have an array this is a handy solution

Answer (score 5):

use `rtrim()`

```
rtrim($string,',');
```

Answer (score 3):

It will impact your script if you work with multi-byte text that you substring from. If this is the case, I higly recommend enabling mb_* functions in your php.ini or do this `ini_set("mbstring.func_overload", 2);`

```
$string = "'test1', 'test2', 'test3',";
echo mb_substr($string, 0, -1);
```

Answer (score 3):

its as simple as:

```
$commaseparated_string = name,name2,name3,;
$result = rtrim($commaseparated_string,',');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of the following technique to remove the last comma(,)

**Solution1:**

```
$string = "'name', 'name2', 'name3',";  // this is the full string or text.
$string = chop($string,",");            // remove the last character (,) and store the updated value in $string variable.
echo $string;                           // to print update string.
```

**Solution 2:**

```
$string = '10,20,30,';              // this is the full string or text.
$string = rtrim($string,',');
echo $string;                       // to print update string.
```

**Solution 3:**

```
 $string = "'name', 'name2', 'name3',";  // this is the full string or text.
 $string = substr($string , 0, -1);
 echo $string;
```

Comment: `chop` is an alias of `rtrim`

Answer (score 0):

Solutions to apply during a loop:

```
//1 - Using conditional:

$source = array (1,2,3);
$total = count($source);
    
$str = null;
    
for($i=0; $i <= $total; $i++){ 
        
    if($i < $total) {
        $str .= $i.',';
    }
    else {
        $str .= $i;
    }
}
    
echo $str; //0,1,2,3

//2 - Using rtrim:

$source = array (1,2,3);
$total = count($source);

$str = null;

for($i=0; $i <= $total; $i++){ 
    
        $str .= $i.',';
}

$str = substr($str,0,strlen($str)-1);
echo $str; //0,1,2,3
```