# How to remove the last comma of array in PHP mail?

Tags: php, arrays, email

How to remove the last comma of array? currently the result is
 "apple,orange,papaya,"

i wan the result is "apple,orange,papaya"

```
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
        $message.= " ".$Cbox[$i].", ";}
```

Comment: Search stackoverflow question before asking. Real duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408691/how-to-remove-last-comma-from-string-using-php

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) for this.

`$trimmed_message = rtrim($message, ",");`

A possible alternative would be to add each item to an array, and then [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it afterwards. For example,

```
$message_items = [];

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
   $message_items[] = $Cbox[$i];
}

$message = implode(", ", $message_items);
```

Comment: Why make `$message_items`? Can't `$Cbox` just be used?

Comment: It could be, but I don't know the full structure of intent of the users code, so I created a new variable for the sake of example.

Answer (score 0):

> use `join()` function

```
 $message = join(",",$Cbox);
```

> or use `implode()` function

```
 $message = implode(",",$Cbox);
```

Comment: you know join ins an alias of implode?

Answer (score 0):

U can use `rtrim()` and remove the last , from the string

```
Ex : rtrim($message,', ');
```